# Estructura de la instrucción for (secciones opcionales)

Tags: c#, bucle-for

revisando la documentación de C# de Microsoft, dice esto sobre la instrucción de iteración for:

*"La instrucción for define las secciones inicializador, condición e iterador".*

Y especifica: **"Las tres secciones son opcionales".**

Estuve buscando pero no encontré nada sobre qué pasa si no coloco alguna de las 3 secciones, también probé con algunas opciones pero no entendí, ¿Para que está la opción de dejar vacíos los campos de inicialización, condición e iteración? O en qué caso se necesitaría dejarlos vacíos? Gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y probaste en tu visual que sucede?

Comment: Claro!!! Entiendo que si dejo todos vacíos sería un bucle infinito, aunque si dejo la primera y la ultima vacías pasa prácticamente lo mismo, el ciclo no tiene fin, pero para qué me podría servir algo así?

Answer (score 0):

pues mira
Te puedes guiar de este ejemplo de como sería llenarlo para que puedas introducirlo en lo que sea tu programa

```
for (int i = x; i < y; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Si hablamos a lo que se refiere el inicializador, es poder declarar una variable que no se encuentre en la clase que estés trabajando ejemplo

```
int i=5
```

Ahora en el condicional, hay que tener en cuenta que lo que quieras hacer deber ser declarado como BOOL en donde se hayan creado dichas variables, teniendo así que

> Si la sección condición no está presente o la expresión booleana se evalúa como true, se ejecutará la siguiente iteración del bucle; en caso contrario, se sale del bucle.
>   A que me refiero con esto que acabo de citar, que sea la condición que tenga establecida en este te va a marcar según el espacio establecido, sino, mostrara el otro procedimiento anexado, en el caso del principio es:

```
i<y
```

Ahora finalmente el itinedaror, lo que hará es hacer un procedimiento según lo que se realice en ese bucle. En este caso será que cada vez que lo haga, sume.

```
i++
```

Espero y te sirva.